Google Sheets QUERY is returning with a no column found errors
I have two sheets.
The master has a ton of data and columns A:EY with about 600 rows
R col is the name of the person
CE col is the value of their deposit (formatted in dollars)
I need to import all names and deposits with a value in CE cell to another sheet
Here is the logic to the QUERY:
IF CE is not null,
RETURN R (name) AND CE (deposit)
Here is my query:
=QUERY(Importrange("form_url","June 3-7 (Robert Martin)!A1:EY800"), "SELECT S,CE WHERE CE is not null")

The error is:
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: S
When I change the QUERY to:
=QUERY(Importrange("form_url","June 3-7 (Robert Martin)!A1:EY800"), "SELECT *")
it returns ALL the data from the MASTER.. what am I doing wrong??
** I cannot share the form data unfortunately.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Try
=QUERY(Importrange("form_url","June 3-7 (Robert Martin)!A1:EY800"), "SELECT Col19,Col83 WHERE Col83 is not null")

You can't use the column letter references because it's imported data.

AHH!! Excellent, thank you. I have not used Query with external data.. thanks again for your help
